# When I run this code on a simulator it runs perfectly, however it crashes on a real device?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, uilocalnotification

When I run this code on a simulator it runs perfectly, however it crashes on a real device?

```
var num = 0     //or 1  
notificationTime = ["2016-05-30 19:59:42 +0000","2016-05-15 16:54:22 +0000"] 
if notificationTime[num] != ""
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    var newString = NSString(string: "\(notificationTime[num])")

    var str1 = newString.substringToIndex(10)
    var str2 = newString.substringFromIndex(11)
    var finalStr = str1 + "T" + str2

    var dateAsString =  finalStr
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString)!
}
```

It says in the last code that it is nil when I run it on a real device, on simulator works perfectly!

```
var arrLocalNotif = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications

for localN:UILocalNotification in arrLocalNotif!
{
    var notificationFireDate:NSDate = localN.fireDate!

    if notificationFireDate == newDate
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localN)
    }
}
```

Comment: and the crash reason is ? what do u mean by last code ? is newDate nil ?

Comment: agreed what crash error are you getting?

Comment: Does the simulator and the device have the same iOS version?

Comment: i get this error 
->  0x1002ae588 <+44>:  brk    #0x1
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

and yeah the simulator has the same version of the device !
newDate  converts string to nsdate

Comment: Is your device iPhone 6 plus ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the `UILocalNotification` instances does not have a `fireDate`, but you force unwrap it. You probably want something like this instead of what you got at the moment:

```
for localN:UILocalNotification in arrLocalNotif! {   
     if let notificationFireDate = localN.fireDate where notificationFireDate == newDate {
         UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localN)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's dates are parsed differently on device and simulator. You initialize date formatter with `NSLocale.currentLocale()`. If you use different locales on device and simulator, it can be a problem.

You can check if `newDate` is not `nil` after calling `dateFromString` on device.

If problem in date formatter, then try to set it up the way as your date strings are formatted, or use `NSCalendar` API to synthesize dates you need as `NSDate` objects, instead of parsing it from string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing dates as strings to use as data (that is, not displaying them to the user) and you want reliable conversion at each end then use ISO date formats and set your date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` as described by Apple in "Parsing Date Strings" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

Otherwise, you *will* fail at some point, since other locales will be affected by user settings and be different between devices. Certainly don't use the "style" options on `NSDateFormatter`. They are for creating user-facing strings from dates, and should never be used to convert strings into dates.